# React native zIndex not working on Views

Tags: javascript, z-index, react-native

Somehow react native zIndex fails to work on this piece of code...

```
<View>
    <View style={{backgroundColor: 'red', width: 100, height: 100, zIndex: 1, position: 'absolute', top: 0, right: 0}}/>
    <View style={{backgroundColor: 'blue', width: 50, height: 50, zIndex: 0, position: 'absolute', top: 0, right: 0}}/>
</View>
```

[image: preview]

If anyone can explain to me why this is "not working" that would be great!

(btw, this is on Android React-native version 0.45.1)

---

This is my workflow atm:

index.android.js

```
import React from 'react-native';
import Viewport from './app/Viewport';

React.AppRegistry.registerComponent('TSK', () => Viewport);
```

Viewport.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    View,
    StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';

// Viewport
export default class Viewport extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <View style={{backgroundColor: 'red', width: 100, height: 100, zIndex: 1, position: 'absolute', top: 0, right: 0}}/>
                <View style={{backgroundColor: 'blue', width: 50, height: 50, zIndex: 0, position: 'absolute', top: 0, right: 0}}/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Viewport', () => Viewport);
```

Comment: I tried your code in expo its working fine, have you tried in real device or only emulator.

Comment: I will try to run it on my android phone.. What do you mean with "only emulator"?

Edit: Same behaviour on my android phone :(

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/H1lbrbAVW check this link

Comment: In your expo i also see that the 'blue' view is visible, which it shouldnt be because of the "zIndex: 0"?

Comment: Ah i see. Somehow it still doesnt work on my end.. I added my workflow to the post, maybe im doing something wrong there?

Comment: Remove AppRegistry.registerComponent('Viewport', () => Viewport); in Viewport.js. You only need to call ones this function to start your main component or screen.

Comment: Ah okay. Sadly this didnt fix the zIndex issue ..